# NetChain with LinearLayer before a NetFoldOperator, how do I make the memory work?

Tags: recursion, neural-networks

I have problems using a recurring network built using the `NetFoldOperator` in cascade to a `LinearLayer`. What happens is that the memory is reset at each input without keeping memory in the window.

This is the example:

```
W = NetInitialize@
   LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 2, "Weights" -> {{1, 1}}, 
    "Biases" -> None];
core = NetGraph[<|
    "fun" -> 
     ThreadingLayer[#1 + #2 &]|>, {{NetPort["in"], NetPort["In2"]} -> 
     "fun" -> NetPort["out"]}];
dyn = NetFoldOperator[core, {"out" -> "In2"}];
complex = NetChain[{W, dyn}];
```

Output of the dyn network (* 1+0=1 => 1+2=3 => 3+3=6 *):

```
dyn[{1, 2, 3}] (* -> {1., 3., 6.} *)
```

Output of the complex network (* {1, 2}*W=3+0=3 => {1, 2}*W=3+0=3 => {1, 2}*W=3+0=3 *):

```
complex[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}] (* -> {{3.}, {3.}, {3.}} *)
```

The memory is reseted every input. How can this be avoided?

How can you get an output like `complex[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}] (* -> {{3.}, {6.}, {9.}} *)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LinearLayer takes a length-2 vector as input, not the whole matrix. Because of that,

complex[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}] is interpreted as:

{complex[{1,2}],complex[{1,2}],complex[{1,2}]} instead.

In the end, the input of the dyn layer is just a single length-1 vector {3}, instead of {3,3,3}.

You want to apply the LinearLayer to each length-2 vector in the input, and output a list of the results to the dyn layer. For that, wrap your LinearLayer inside a NetMapOperator:

```
W = NetInitialize@
   LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 2, "Weights" -> {{1, 1}}, 
    "Biases" -> None];
core = NetGraph[<|
    "fun" -> 
     ThreadingLayer[Plus]|>, {{NetPort["in"], NetPort["In2"]} -> 
     "fun" -> NetPort["out"]}, "out" -> 1];
dyn = NetFoldOperator[core, {"out" -> "In2"}];
complex = NetChain[{NetMapOperator[W], dyn}];
```

That way you have:

complex[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}] => {{3.}, {6.}, {9.}}